# Page reloads on Clicking apex commandlink though reRender is set to None

Tags: visualforce, javascript, ajax

I have an issue in apex:commandlink  ,On  clicking apex commandlink the page gets reloaded though i have set my reRender property to none.This works in chrome but not working in firefox and IE this seems to be strange any  ideas on this?

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="" >
    <apex:commandLink id="searchzip" styleClass="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="color:#666565;" onclick="Call(); " reRender="none" status="Search"/>
</button>
<apex:actionStatus id="Search" onstart="showControl();" onstop="hideControl();" />
```

this is my  button

Comment: what does `onlclick=call();` do?

Comment: onclick im calling java script but the same functionlaity works in chrome

Comment: Well then i guess wrapping VF component inside standard HTML is causing some issues. Does it work fine without the outer `<button>`?

Comment: note that `rerender="none"` tries to rerender a VF component with `id="none"`

Answer (score 1):

To make the commandLink look like a button you just need to specify `styleClass="btn"`. You dont need to wrap it inside html button. Perhaps that is what is causing the refresh.

And not sure what your `onclick` is calling.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandLink.htm), `reRender` option:

> The ID of one or more components that are redrawn when the result of an AJAX update request returns to the client. This value can be a single ID, a comma-separated list of IDs, or a merge field expression for a list or collection of IDs.

So if you don't want to refresh your page, remove this `reRender` statement from your `commandLink`